# Add /EHa to QtCreator that used Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, visual-c++, qt-creator

How can I add `/EHa` (Structured Exception Handling) in QtCreator for MS Compiler.
I’ve been used Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler.

Answer (score 5):

This is how to do it. Works both for Qt 4 and Qt 5. This will set EHa instead of default EHsc:

```
win* {
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_EXCEPTIONS_ON = /EHa
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_STL_ON = /EHa
}
```

Comment: Still works with Qt 6.

Answer (score 0):

In your project file, add:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /EHa
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It works with other flags, but no with /EHa. I assume it gets overriden by qmake.spec.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the QtDIR and mkspecs and choose folder of compiler

and then open qmake.conf and edit

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE to 

QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = -EHA
```

Comment: Editing qmake.conf is a hack and is not portable (as in, you have to do it for every Qt version on every machine you work on). See my answer for a portable way that only requires editing your .pro file.